# Prove that some local noetherian integral domain is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> A local noetherian integral domain $A$ is a field if the unique maximal ideal $m$ satisfies $m^n = m^{n+1}$ for some $n\in N$

I think it should be related to Nakayama lemma, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Take $M=m^n$ in Nakayama's Lemma.

Comment: another question is whether we need integral domain in the proof?

Comment: @annimal Yes, since from NAK you get $m^n=0$ and need to conclude $m=0$. For example, if $R=K[X]/(X^2)$ then $m=(x)$ satisfies $m^2=0$, so $m^n=m^{n+1}$ for all $n\ge 2$ and $R$ is not a field.